# Subset dataframe in R using grep with reactive variables

Tags: r, shiny, subset, reactive-programming

My data frame **df** has column names such as **aplication2011, winner2012**, etc.

In my Shiny application I use 2 reactive variables:

```
year = reaction$year
category = reaction$category
```

defined in my UI. R as:

```
radioButtons("year", label = h3("Year:"),
                           choices = list("2011" = "2011", "2012" = "2012",
                                          "2013" = "2013", "2014" = "2014", 
                                          "2015" = "2015", "2016"= "2016"),selected = 1)),

 radioButtons("category", label = h3("Category"), 
                          choices = list("Aplicant" = "aplic", 
                                         "Winner" = "win",
```

My goal is to subset my data frame **df** using this two variables which contain *parts* of variable names.

For example if  **reaction$year** is selected **2011** and **reaction$category** is chosen **ap** I should get column **aplication2011**

and I am trying to subset using:

```
# kindly regards to user lmo for providing this code
getMap <- function(df, reaction){
# get user selected content from getReaction function
userReaction <- getReaction(category, year)

# extract from list returned by function
yearSelect <- userReaction[["year"]]
catSelect <- userReaction[["category"]]
# extract variable
df <- df[[names(df)[grep(paste0("^", catSelect, .*, yearSelect, "$"),
                               names(df), value=TRUE)]]]
```

My reactive function:

```
getReaction2 <- reactive({
return(list(category = input$category,
year = input$year
))
```

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the superfast reply. I made a try but I get: Error in <-: attempt to set an attribute on NULL

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that reaction$category contains the *beginning* of a variable name and reaction$year contains the full year of the variable name, you could use the following expression to pull out variables:

```
# get user selected content from getReaction function
# extract from list returned by function
yearSelect <- getReaction[["year"]]
catSelect <- getReaction[["category"]]
# extract variable
myVariable <- df[[names(df)[grep(paste0("^", catSelect, ".*", yearSelect, "$"),
                              names(df), value=TRUE)]]]
```

Comment: Cannot find function getReaction. What should I put instead of dots?

Comment: In your previous edit, you had a function named `getReaction` that, as I understood it, returned a list of length 2 containing the "year" and "category" selected by the user. Where is the function that returns user selections?

Comment: Just call `getReaction2`  `getReaction` as you did previously. Also, please remove my answer from your question or add a note that you copied it from my answer.

Comment: Sorry for plagiarize. What should I add instead of dots in getReaction brackets?

Comment: Please check your regular expression. It says that some quotes is not neccessary

Comment: Thank you. Still no result just object 'getReaction2' not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115233/discussion-between-user1997567-and-lmo).